# On MacOS, how can you access a different users files?

Tags: python, macos

I am using a jupyter notebook running python 3.6 for data analysis on one users account. However, I need to access data from another users files on the same computer. Aside from moving the data to the same users files, is there a way I can access the files?

Answer (score 0):

You need `Jupyter lab`: Website:https://jupyterlab.readthedocs.io/en/stable/

First do:

```
cd /Users/
```

then

```
jupyter lab
```

In this case, you can easily navigate among users folders.

[image]